# Align the 3 last child of a menu to the right without reversing order

Tags: html, css, css-float

Well I'm trying to reorder the last 3 options of a menu without reversing it's order...

```css
ul {
  width: 100%;
}

ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style-type: none;
}

ul li:nth-last-child(-n+3) {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
  <li>8</li>
  <li>9</li>
  <li>10</li>
</ul>
```

But as you can see, the menu display 10-9-8, instead of 8-9-10, I have see something about `direction: ltr;` but without luck.

Any tips?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can instead float try flex and use `margin-left:auto` to push element on the right like this :

```css
ul {
  display:flex;
}

ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

ul li:nth-child(8) {
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
  <li>8</li>
  <li>9</li>
  <li>10</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

try this way

```css
ul {
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-flex;
}

ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

ul li:nth-last-child(3) {
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
  <li>8</li>
  <li>9</li>
  <li>10</li>
</ul>
```